# Configuración para proxy pass solo funciona con /

Tags: nginx, configuración, proxy

Tengo una aplicación y un blog de WordPress en [WP Engine](https://wpengine.com/):

- Ejemplo de la aplicación: `https://www.myapp.com`
- Ejemplo del blog: `https://myapp.wpengine.com/blog/`

Lo que quiero hacer es usar Nginx para hacer un proxy pass hacia la URL del blog en WP Engine, de tal forma que si ingreso a `https://www.myapp.com/blog/` me muestre el contenido de `https://myapp.wpengine.com/blog/`. Para esto cree un nuevo location en mi configuración Nginx (además de algunas modificaciones por el lado del WP Engine):

```
location /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Is-Reverse-Proxy "true";

    proxy_pass http://myapp.wpengine.com;
}
```

Esto está funcionando bien, me muestra, por ejemplo, las siguientes URLs:

- `https://www.myapp.com/blog/`
- `https://www.myapp.com/blog/2017/08/09/our-new-blog/`
- `https://www.myapp.com/blog/?s=test`

Mi problema surgió cuando intenté acceder específicamente a `https://www.myapp.com/blog` (sin `/` al final), lo que pasa cuando uso esto es que me redirige a `https://myapp.wpengine.com/blog/`. Entonces lo que intenté fue cambiar a una expresión regular para considerar la presencia y ausencia de `/`:

```
location ~ ^/blog/?(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Is-Reverse-Proxy "true";

    proxy_pass http://myapp.wpengine.com;
}
```

Pero esto tampoco ha funcionado. ¿Sabe alguien qué tengo que hacer para que funcione?

Comment: Prueba: `location ^~ /blog { ... proxy_pass http://myapp.wpengine.com/; } `